# About the AVPlayerLayer crash for KVO key path operationCount

Tags: avplayer, key-value-observing

recent I used AVPlayer to play while downloading, everything seems fine. Bug I found some crash about AVPlayerLayer.

**the error info like this:**

An instance 0x170038f60 of class AVPlayerLayer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x174e38040> ( NSKeyValueObservance 0x17465ec90: Observer: 0x170a62c40, Key path: **operationCount**, Options: New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x17465ede0> )

I can't reproduce and don't know how to solve it. Can you please help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the player layer is getting released but the observer is still attached to it.

You should remove the **playerLayerObserver** and **PlayerItemObservers**, which you have previously added to your **AVPlayerLayer** and **AVPlayerItem** instances in the **deinit** method of your viewController.

```
deinit {
    guard videoPlayer != nil else { return }
    self.playerLayer.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: PlayerReadyForDisplayKey, context: &PlayerLayerObserverContext)
    removePlayerItemObservers(item: self.avPlayerItem)

    videoPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
}
```

This way you can remove observer

```
internal func removePlayerItemObservers(item: AVPlayerItem) {
    if (item.observationInfo != nil) {
        //NOTE:- REMOVE ONLY FOR THE OBSERVERS THAT YOU HAVE ADDED PREVIOUSLY ON ITEM
        item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
        item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
        item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty")
        item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
        item.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isPlaybackBufferFull")
    }
}
```

Try and share the result.

Comment: 3ks for your reply, my problem is not complete，and i had update my answer.  I don't know why the crash is key path for "operationCount", because I never register it